# Rewrite subquery with calculation in SQL to CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have, as a part of a bigger query, some subqueries that I would like to convert to CASE statements instead.

The subquery looks like this (and works):

```
(SELECT (((SUM(DAm)-(SUM(StcCst)*-1))*100)/NULLIF(SUM(DAm),0)) AS 'DG' FROM [F0001].[dbo].[ProdTr] WHERE AcYrPr = '201601' AND ProdTr.TrTp = 1 AND [F0001].[dbo].[ProdTr].CustNo = '12773') AS dg_period_1
```

However, I don't seem to find any logical way to put this into a CASE-statement.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does the subquery return only 1 row? Whey do you want to convert it into a case statement? Try to recreated your scenario with some sample data and show your expected output based on that.

Comment: @Utsav It contains an aggregate function and no group-statement, it _DOES_ return exactly 1 row (not more and not less)

Comment: I see an issue with `NULLIF(SUM(DAm), 0)` since you cannot divide a number by null. What do you want to do if `SUM(DAm)` is null?

Comment: @Sunil: Thats what the NULLIF is for, isn't it?

Comment: NULLIF will return a null value if SUM(DAm) = 0. That would cause division by null which is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(
    SELECT  CASE
                WHEN SUM(t1.DAm) <> 0
                THEN (SUM(t1.DAm) + SUM(t1.StcCst)) * 100 / SUM(t1.DAm)
                ELSE 0 /* or whatever you want to have in this case */
            END AS 'DG' 
    FROM    [F0001].[dbo].[ProdTr] t1
    WHERE   t1.AcYrPr = '201601' AND
            t1.TrTp = 1 AND
            t1.CustNo = '12773'
) AS dg_period_1
```

I also removed some unneeded parentheses and simplified an operation `(x - (y * -1) = x + y)`

Comment: This is why I love this comminity. This works PERFECTLY! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: sorry, I was too fast

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following statement with `CASE` provided you want to return a null when SUM(DAm) is null or 0.

```
(SELECT CASE
              WHEN SUM(DAm) IS NOT NULL and SUM(DAm)  <> 0 THEN (((SUM(DAm) - (SUM(StcCst) * -1)) * 100) /SUM(DAm))
              ELSE NULL
          END AS 'DG'
   FROM [F0001].[dbo].[ProdTr]
   WHERE AcYrPr = '201601'
     AND ProdTr.TrTp = 1
     AND [F0001].[dbo].[ProdTr].CustNo = '12773') AS dg_period_1
```